# "Invalid column name" when syncing tables

Tags: sql

I am converting an old stored procedure for a legacy app to a newer app.

```
SELECT ContainerID, SizeID.Desc, TypeID.Desc, UOMID.Desc
FROM [Online].dbo.Master
INNER JOIN [Online].dbo.Type TypeID ON Master.TypeID = TypeID.NumID
INNER JOIN [Online].dbo.Size SizeID ON Master.SizeID = SizeID.NumID
INNER JOIN [Online].dbo.Measure MeasureID ON Master.MeasureID = MeasureID.NumID
```

When I run this I'm getting an Invalid column name error for the the 3 columns above in the other database I am supposed to be syncing to and I am not sure why.

Comment: It is unlikely this problem has anything to do with stored procedures, and likely that it is simply of consequence on not specifying the tables of origin of the fields in the SELECT clause; and possibly problems stemming from trying to join tables on their aliases, and not a field (or using a field names as a table aliases). _Also, this is not MySQL, though it would have similar complaints about such a query._

Comment: I removed your mutually incompatible dbms tags. Please add the single tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple table have same field, so the engine doesnt know what field are you refering to. And cause that Ambiguous error.

```
 SELECT ContainerID, SizeID, TypeID, UOMID
                             ^^
                             can came from Master or Type
```

use something like

```
 SELECT ContainerID, Master.SizeID, Master.TypeID, UOMID
```

If you want bring values from both tables, you need use alias to diferenciate.

```
 SELECT ContainerID, Master.SizeID, 
        Master.TypeID firstType,
        Type.TypeID secondType
```